# Does pdb provide information about type definitions in source files?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, assemblies, pdb-files

I know about DIA api, dbghelp. But can i use them to extract type definition location info   such as file, begin_line, begin_column, end_line, end_column from my assembly and pdb generated?

If the answer is yes, can someone point me to the simple example out there?

Comment: When you get the answer, I would like to know as well :)

Comment: FYI: classes/structs can be (and often are) partial.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [Common Compiler Infrastructure - Metadata](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) project on codeplex. It can read pdb files, but there's no way I can see of getting a source location for a class, just members.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, Look at Mono.Cecil